# Is their a way to change values in jolt transformation and replace them with custom values

Tags: java, json, jolt

I have a jolt transformation

```json
{
  "response": [
    {
      "requestDate": 1655285978000,
      "title": "White"
    },
    {
      "requestDate": 1655193656000,
      "title": "White"
    }
  ]
}
```

In my jolt transformation, I want the value of white to be replaced with black, so that the  output should become.

```json
{
  "response": [
    {
      "requestDate": 1655285978000,
      "title": "Black"
    },
    {
      "requestDate": 1655193656000,
      "title": "Black"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a way the content in jolt.

Comment: JOLT is more of a static structure. Dynamic modifications can be done by using JOLT Shiftr maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a conditional to separate the cases of the values of title attributes as **`White`** and the ***others*** within a **shift** transformation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "response": {
        "*": {
          "title": {
            "White": {
              "#Black": "&4[&3].&2" // &4 : to substitute "response"(in order to reach four levels up and grab the value), [&3] : to substitute indexes of "response" array, &2 : to get "White" by traversing : and {, eg. two levels up.
            },
            "*": {
              "@1": "&4[&3].&2"
            }
          },
          "*": "&2[&1].&2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may consider another library *Josson*.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

Deserialization

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "  \"response\": [" +
    "    {" +
    "      \"requestDate\": 1655285978000," +
    "      \"title\": \"White\"" +
    "    }," +
    "    {" +
    "      \"requestDate\": 1655193656000," +
    "      \"title\": \"White\"" +
    "    }" +
    "  ]" +
    "}");
```

Transformation

```
JsonNode node = josson.getNode(
    "response" +
    ".field(title.caseValue('White','Black',?))" +
    ".toObject('response')");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

Output

```
{
  "response" : [ {
    "requestDate" : 1655285978000,
    "title" : "Black"
  }, {
    "requestDate" : 1655193656000,
    "title" : "Black"
  } ]
}
```